# how to prevent from exiting or jump out elements from page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use several buttons to create motion, now i have a problem when i use `marginLeft` for move the element to left and right `div#ball`, it doesn't fit in the page and  jumps out and exit form both left and right side. how i can set a limitation and avoid element from exiting ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fastleft').click(function() {
    $('#ball').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('#ball').animate({
      'marginLeft': "-=300px"
    });
  });

  $('#moveleft').click(function() {
    $('#ball').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('#ball').animate({
      'marginLeft': "-=20px"
    });
  });

  $('#moveright').click(function() {
    $('#ball').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('#ball').animate({
      'marginLeft': "+=20px"
    });
  });

  $('#fastright').click(function() {
    $('#ball').toggleClass('rotated');
    $('#ball').animate({
      'marginLeft': "+=300px"
    });
  });

});
```

```css
#ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*background-image: url(./boll.png);*/
  background-color:red;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.rotated {
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-name: ball;
}

@keyframes ball {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(100deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(200deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(300deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="butts">
    <button id="fastleft" type="button">FastLeft</button></button>
    <button id="moveleft" type="button">Left</button>
    <button id="moveright" type="button">Right</button>
    <button id="fastright" type="button">FastRight</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a more optimized version of your code using `function` and `data` attribute. Examine it and let me know if you have any questions understanding it.

```js
var ball = $('#ball');
var position = 0;
var bw = ball.width();
var ww = $('body').width();

$('button').click(function() {    
  var speed = $(this).data('speed');
  moveBall(speed);
});


function moveBall(px){
  position+= px;
  position = Math.min(position,ww-bw);
  position = Math.max(position,0);
  
  console.log(position);

  ball.toggleClass('rotated').animate({
      'marginLeft': position+"px"
  });
}
```

```css
    #ball {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      /*background-image: url(./boll.png);*/
      background-color:red;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      position: relative;
    }

    .rotated {
      animation-duration: 0.5s;
      animation-name: ball;
    }

    @keyframes ball {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(100deg)
      }
      25% {
        transform: rotate(200deg)
      }
      50% {
        transform: rotate(300deg)
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div id="butts">
        <button data-speed="-300" id="fastleft" type="button">FastLeft</button>
        <button data-speed="-20" id="moveleft" type="button">Left</button>
        <button data-speed="20" id="moveright" type="button">Right</button>
        <button data-speed="300" id="fastright" type="button">FastRight</button>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="ball"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using other CSS properties like float and align instead of  giving such large values in pixel to margin or padding properties. This will almost always push your elements out of your page especially if you are working with small screen sizes . Also you should try using bootstrap. It will make your life much easier.